# From timestamp to Date Android

Tags: android, date, kotlin, timestamp

Good day, I have timestamp `1481709600` and I would like to have this time format `Wed, 14 Dec 2016`

I'm trying to do that using:

```
private String getDateFromTimeStamp(Integer dt) {
            Date date = new Date (dt);
            return new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy ").format(date);
}
```

but the current output is `Sun Jan 18 05:35:09 GMT+02:00 1970`

I think the date format is wrong, which one I need to use ?

Thank you!

***Update***

the problem is that the year day and month is wrong, It should be 14 Dec 2016 instead of Jan 18 1970

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem is your timeStamp is in seconds , so convert your timeStamp into millisec and then use the date format function ...**

try this one ...

> JAVA

```
 private String getDate(long time) {
        Date date = new Date(time*1000L); // *1000 is to convert seconds to milliseconds
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy "); // the format of your date
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4"));
    
        return sdf.format(date);;
    }
```

> Kotlin

```
fun getDate(time:Long):String {
            var date:Date = Date(time*1000L); // *1000 is to convert seconds to milliseconds
            var sdf:SimpleDateFormat  = SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy "); // the format of your date
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4"));
    
        return sdf.format(date);
    }
```

Output:- like this [image: Wed, 14 Dec 2016]

Note:- **`EEE`** is represent as Day in Week ,**`MMM`** is represent as Month in words and so on ..

Answer (score 2):

You can make any combination if you read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
You need to use `EEE, d MMM yyyy`

**Update**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy");
sdf.format(new Date(1481709600));
```

Answer (score 0):

the dateformat is wrong;  you have to use the

```
 new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").format(date);
```

Comment: use long instead of integer

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to get data. Put the time in setTimeInMillis as long and not as int

```
private String getDate(long time) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
    String date = DateFormat.format("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy ", cal).toString();
    return date;
}
```

Comment: @VLeonovs 1481709600*1000 then it gives you correct date. I already have mentioned you setTimeInMillis.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private String getDateFromTimeStamp(long time) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
        cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
        String date = DateFormat.format("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy ", cal).toString();
        return date;
    }
```

Comment: @VLeonovs what is the timestamp you are passing. the mistake that you have done is , you have used `Integer` value as the parameter which should be `long` datatype that is y u where getting 1970 as the year, try the code above and revert if you are getting same output

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
val currentDay = Date()
    val day = currentDay.time
    Logger.i("currentDay = $currentDay and day : $day ")

    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    c.timeInMillis = day
    val d = c.time
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")

    Logger.i("meDate : ${sdf.format(d)}")
```